# Chainlink oracles on testnet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, chainlink

Good day, everyone!
I'm currently developing smart contracts and using Chainlink oracles to obtain external data; I've searched the Chainlink market for oracle addresses and job ids, but no oracles are currently responding or providing data in kovan, rinkeyby testnetwork, i.e. when I fetch a URL in a smart contract, Chainlink oracles are failing to provide any data to the smart contract. I'm not sure how to fix this problem, and I'm not sure if the problem is for me or any one else?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what I did is I tested it on other networks and on mumbai (polygon testnet) it works for me. I use `0x0bDDCD124709aCBf9BB3F824EbC61C87019888bb` node with job `35738ec3cf9f4fd296b17bb91fdda32e` (post > byte32) so you could eventually try this one as well if it fits your needs